# Iterate through SQL table creating another SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

Wonder if someone could cast an eye over the following problem:

I'm running a `SQL SELECT` statement which gives me the following results:

```
DATE          NumberOfHours

2017-05-01       4

2017-06-01       38

2017-07-01       68
```

And what I'm trying (like to be able to) to do is off the back of this table create another table that contains `4 rows for 2017-05-01`, `38 Rows for 2017-06-01` and `68 rows for 2017-07-01`. So I end up with a table that's got 110 rows in it.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how this could be achieved...could anyone assist?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Using the response listed by Gordon Linoff I managed to get this working working by using:

```
with cte as (
SELECT  DATEADD(month, datediff(month,0,L.DateAdded),0) AS 'Date', CEILING(SUM(l.CPDHours))AS NumberOfHours
FROM WebsiteICA_SF.dbo.CPD_Log L
WHERE L.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) 
AND (L.Provider = 'ICA' OR L.Provider like 'International Compli%')
GROUP BY DATEADD(month, datediff(month,0,L.DateAdded),0)
  union all
  select date, NumberOfHours - 1
  from cte
  where NumberOfHours > 1

 )
select 1 AS 'ObId', date, 'ICA' AS Provider, '# ICA' AS DataType
from cte
order by DATEADD(month, datediff(month,0,cte.Date),0)

OPTION (maxrecursion 10000);
```

Comment: Please post your table definitions and data

Comment: This is temporary table that's being built on the fly. The Date field is a DateTime and the NumberOfRows is an Integer. Thanks C

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the rows that are created.  Perhaps a little context would help people understand?  Also, which database?

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment, LOL.  Have you thought about it at all -- have any code started, that we could look at?  Hints:  `CREATE TABLE` could create your table.  Do an internet search on "T-SQL WHILE" and look at the "Examples" section to see how to use WHILE.  Looks like 3 `WHILE` statements to me, incrementing variables you `DECLARE`d to keep count of how many rows you `INSERT`ed.

Comment: The data is being passed from the STP into c# controller, which ultimately converts the data into a series of variables and passes this them onto charting scripting blocks which sums the data by month. Using my C# brain I'm pretty sure that I could loop through the resultset assign a variable to the NumberOfHours and then do an insert loop While i < Variable total. just wondering if there's a better way in SQL thish could be done.

Comment: Plus I think I'd be using a cursor which I'm told is bad.......thinking you're getting the idea that I'm no SQL expert!

Comment: It helps to think about what goes in the resulting table and where that data would come from. That would reduce how hard you are working to create a bunch of empty meaningless rows. If the date corresponds somewhere to a set of that number of rows, you already have your table for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple method is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select date, NumberOfHours
      from t
      union all
      select date, NumberOfHours - 1
      from cte
      where NumberOfHours > 1
     )
select date
from cte;
```

By default, this is limited to a maximum of 100 hours.  However, that is easily changed using the `MAXRECURSION` option.

Other methods generally rely on a second table to generate numbers.  I also like this approach because it is a gentle introduction to recursive CTEs.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ea3f8b/1) is a nice SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a result set with 3 rows and one column in it which tells you how many rows it represents. You want to generate that many rows.

Not sure what you want to store in that, but here is a solution to the base problem:

Create a table (temp table or CTE is fine too) which contains only one column, storing numbers from 0 to whatever. This is called `Tally Table` or `Numbers Table`.

Join this table to your resultset:

```
WITH NumbersCTE AS (
  -- This will give you a bunch of Numbers
  -- Persist a table if you want to use it more frequently
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS Number FROM sys.columns
)
SELECT
  MT.Date,
  N.Number
FROM
  dbo.MyTable MT
  INNER JOIN NumbersCTE N
    ON N.Number <= MT.NumberOfHours
```

As Pieter Geerkens pointed out in the comments, the above method is not the best to generate a numbers table, but for demostration puposes it is fine.

For more info about how to generat tally tables in SQL Server, you can check 
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/

Comment: As the number of rows in **sys.columns** is fairly modest, by modern standards, you might want to point OP at a *Ben-Gan* style tally table, as [outlined here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens For the sake of showing how to use it, it is more than enough. Personally, I hate when it is done on the fly, I always have a persisted util.Numbers table in my databases. However your link is useful, and I know about it, I will add it to the answer as further reference.

Comment: Thanks folks, I shall have a bash at this and report back :)